# rapidminer if else statement for attribute generation

Tags: classification, rapidminer

I have a csv file adult dataset from UCI.
I have an incom attribute whose values are ">50k" or "<=50k". I want to generate an attribue status such that:

if incom=">50k"
status="yes"
else
status="no"

I am not a rapidminer user neither rm have any doc. about this.
I have used these statements:

```
if ( incom == ">50k") status = "yes" else status="no";
if (matches(incom,">50k")) status ="yes" else status="no";
```

and many other. but it says

> implicit multiplication not enabled

how to tackle the problem? Rm allowed to write in single line as you know so the code above is not indented.
Thanks

Comment: Such questions are better asked in the rapidminer forums than in a programming community.

Comment: Which operator do you use? (Set Value?)

Comment: well, rapidminer forums were not responsive. I did complete the work with a solution by @awchisholm Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Generate Attributes` operator lets you create a new attribute with the following tiny bit of "code".

if (incom == ">50k", "yes", "no")

In more detail, in the parameter list of the `Generate Attributes` operator, set the attribute name to be the name of the new attribute you want to create - status for example. Then set the function expression to be the expression above.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get a binominal (boolean) status attribute would be to

1. Generate a copy of the income attribute with the name status (`Generate Copy`)
2. Map numeric to binominal of this status attribute (Numerical to Binominal) with min=0.0 and max=50000